# Xubuntu 13.04 Dual screen HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, xubuntu, 13.04

Im trying to set up a Dual Screen for my Netbook (Asus EEE Pc X101CH) I tried using 'grandr' but cant seem to get the screens to split. Ive looked around but there doesnt seem to be much on the subject.

What is the best way to go around 'splitting' the screens? My graphics driver is Cedar Trail DRM and most of the solutions i found are for nVidia.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.